# ListView con boton en fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Tengo un problema... Me carga la lista pero no me funciona el evento del boton.

fragment_pedido_consultado.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hernan.apptesis.infoUser.pedidoConsultado">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListServices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Ahora:
listview_solicitudes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Estado:"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/estado"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView24"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/estado"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/estado"
    android:text="Ticket:"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ticket"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView26"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Dispositivo:"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipoDispositivos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView29"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Soporte:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Soporte:"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipoSoportes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tipoDispositivos"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Soporte:"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Soporte:"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Soporte:"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Fecha:"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fecha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tipoSoportes"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView33"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/removeSolicitud"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/removemini"
    android:text="Cancelar"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

Por ultimo
pedidoConsultado.java

```
public class pedidoConsultado extends Fragment {

private ListView listado;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
Button remove;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pedido_consultado, container, false);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    listado = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListServices);

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    new cargarServicios(dialog).execute();

    return view;
}//fin onCreateView

public class cargarServicios extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public cargarServicios(ProgressDialog dialog) {
        super();
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setTitle("Procesando...");
        dialog.setMessage("Un momento...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String respuestaPost;

        String ID = obtenerIdentificador();

        httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();

        respuestaPost = handler.cargarServicio(ID);

        return respuestaPost;

    }//fin doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        String[] data = obtDatosJSON(response);
        CargaLista(data);

        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}//fin class cargarServicios

public void CargaLista(String[] services ){

    try{

        AdapterServicios adapter = new AdapterServicios(getActivity(), services);

        listado.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Error en adapter: ",e.getMessage());
    }


}//fin CargarLista

public String[] obtDatosJSON (String response){

    String [] listaServicios = null;

    try{

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i=0; i<= jsonArray.length(); i++){

            String estado           = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("estado");
            String ticket           = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ticket");
            String tipoSoportes     = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipoSoportes");
            String tipoDispositivos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipoDispositivos");
            String fecha            = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("fecha");

            listaServicios = new String[]{ticket,estado,tipoSoportes,tipoDispositivos,fecha};

        }//fin for

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaServicios;
}

private String obtenerIdentificador(){

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("testApp",0);

    String ID = settings.getString("id","0");

    return ID;

}//obtenerIdentificador

}//fin pedidoConsultado
```

Ahora 
AdapterServicios.java

```
public class AdapterServicios extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] items;
private static LayoutInflater inflater= null;

public AdapterServicios(Activity activity, String[] items){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}//fin constructor

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView vTicket;
    TextView vEstado;
    TextView vTipoSoportes;
    TextView vTipoDispositivos;
    TextView vFecha;
    Button vRemove;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder = new Holder();

    View fila;

    fila = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_solicitudes, null);

    holder.vTicket = (TextView) fila.findViewById(R.id.ticket);
    holder.vEstado = (TextView) fila.findViewById(R.id.estado);
    holder.vTipoSoportes = (TextView) fila.findViewById(R.id.tipoSoportes);
    holder.vTipoDispositivos = (TextView) fila.findViewById(R.id.tipoDispositivos);
    holder.vFecha = (TextView) fila.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
    holder.vRemove = (Button) fila.findViewById(R.id.removeSolicitud);

    holder.vTicket.setText(items[0]);
    holder.vEstado.setText(items[1]);
    holder.vTipoSoportes.setText(items[2]);
    holder.vTipoDispositivos.setText(items[3]);
    holder.vFecha.setText(items[4]);

    holder.vRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Presiono",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    fila.setTag(holder);
    return fila;

}//fin getView

}//fin class AdapterServicios
```

Comment: El botón está dentro de cada item del listview cierto?

Comment: @Juan claro es correcto

Comment: Fijate mi respuesta abajo.

Comment: @Juan Acabe de modificar lo tal cual aparece con ListView personalizado pero sigue sin funcionar me el evento de OnClickListener

Comment: @Juan Ya le di con la respuesta, pero no puedo darte reputacion le puse el chulito para que se viera verde, gracias.

Comment: @Juan Aunque solo funciona con la lista xdd no con el boton pero igual me sirvio para seguir..

Comment: No entendi. Cual es la parte que no funciona? Podes agregar el código en la pregunta?

Comment: @Juan Listo, ya lo edite y pues aun no logro hacer lo funcionar cuando agrego el evento del boton me revienta xd pero el de la lista no...

Comment: El onclicklistener ponéselo al boton vRemover no a fila. Si ademas queres recibir los clicks en el item de la lista, lo haces en el MainActivity sobre el listview con setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener) ...

Comment: @Juan el problema viene hay, cuando lo pongo a vRemover este me da error inesperado y no carga ni el ListView

Comment: Antes de return fila, te falta agregar el holder como un tag del view: fila.setTag(holder).

Comment: Dices algo como esto? 

`holder.vRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Presiono",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`

Comment: Exacto y quitar el que tenes puesto en fila.

Comment: Esto sale: `05-28 15:42:26.082 29577-29577/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.hernan.test, PID: 29577
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at`

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el codigo de como lo deje @Juan

Comment: Fijate si findViewById encontró el boton despues de esta linea: holder.vRemove = (Button) fila.findViewById(R.id.removeSolicitud); Es decir si vRemove no es null...

Comment: Claro, el problema va es cuando agrego el holder.vRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { es lo que ando intentando decifrar xd

Comment: El prolema no es ese, sino que no estas levantado el boton del layout en el xml. Si el findViewById te devuelve el botón el resto anda. Fijate si por ahi no le cambiaste el id o si hay algo en rojo en el layout. En el codigo que pegaste parece no estar cerado pero por ahi solo le falta la última linea.

Comment: Acabo de revisar y no hay nada en rojo xd me compila normal y no me tira errores jejeje es frustrante ya... Que me recomiendas que haga? @Juan

Comment: Ahora te subo un ejemplo simple en mi respuesta que hice recien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que ese botón está en cada item del listview, me parece que vas a tener que escribir tu propio adaptador en lugar de usar `SimpleAdapter.`

En el adapter, haciendo el override de `getView()`, donde se infla el item de la lista, buscas el botón del item con `view.findViewById()` y le asignás el manejador del evento con `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){...})`

Al hacerlo ahi, cada botón que se infla en su correspondiente ítem queda con su propio manejador de click.

EDIT 1

[Acá hay ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966689/what-is-the-working-of-settag-and-gettag-in-viewholder-pattern) simple de getView() donde se ve el setTag(holder). Además podés ver como reutiliza views ya instanciados usando el convertview.

EDIT 2

Un ejemplo simple de lo que estuvimos viendo. Fijate que el click en cada boton te dice que boton tocaste 1, 2, o 3.

Main Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ListView listview;
        MyAdapter listAdapter;
        ArrayList<MiData> data;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            data = new ArrayList<>();
            data.add(new MiData("AAAA"));
            data.add(new MiData("BBBB"));
            data.add(new MiData("CCCC"));
            data.add(new MiData("DDDD"));

            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);
            listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

    }
```

MyAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<MiData> data;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<MiData> data){
        this.data = data;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        vh.tv.setText(data.get(i).dato);
        vh.btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClickMe);
        vh.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Click en boton: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv;
        Button btn;
    }
}
```

MiData.java

```
public class MiData {
    String dato;

    public MiData(String dato){
        this.dato = dato;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.johnurrutia.soes_73787.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ejemplo de text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClickMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Cliqueame!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 3

Si además necesitas poder hacer click sobre el item fuera del boton, en main activiy agregás:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click en item: " + i , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

y hay que ponerle al botón del item `focusable:false` en el xml para que el listview reciba los clicks fuera del botón.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Juan de verdad x3